# Same shading for the patches in the same plane (2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-3dplot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot and shade a 3D figure using `patch table with point meta` as in question ["Same shading for the patches in the same plane"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435241/same-shading-for-the-patches-in-the-same-plane), but I am obtaining triangles in the same plane but with a different shade intensity. 
First I process my data with Mathematica to get the shades of a set of points.

In Mathematica:

```
R21 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.436694}, {0, 0.436694, 0.436694}, {0, 
    0.5822, 0.2911}, {0, 0.873387, 0}, {0.291187, 0.5822, 
    0.2911}, {0.436694, 0.436694, 0.436694}, {0.873387, 0, 
    0}, {0.873387, 0, 0.436694}};

R = ConvexHullMesh[R21]
```

[image]

And now I compute the list of vertices of each triangle of the figure with its color in the last column:

```
lookuptable = 
  AssociationThread[Range[MeshCellCount[R, 0]], 
   Flatten[Nearest[R21 -> Automatic, MeshCoordinates[R]]]];

faces = Partition[
   Lookup[lookuptable, 
    Flatten[MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]], 3];
closedfaces = Join[faces, faces[[All, {1}]], 2] - 1;

lsttriangles = {};
Do[x = R21[[closedfaces[[i, 1]] + 1]] - R21[[closedfaces[[i, 2]] + 1]];
  y = R21[[closedfaces[[i, 1]] + 1]] - 
    R21[[closedfaces[[i, 3]] + 1]];
  z = Cross[x, y];
  AppendTo[lsttriangles, 
   Join[Take[closedfaces[[i]], 3], {Abs[z.{1, 2, 3}/Sqrt[z.z]]}]], {i,
    1, Length[closedfaces]}];
```

where `lsttriangles` contains the list of vertices of the figure with the intensity-color data.

Using this data, I can plot the figure with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=126,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
            % colormap/greenyellow,
            colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!80!black!90) color(2)=(blue!80!black!70) color(3)=(blue!80!black!50) color(4)=(blue!80!black!30)},
            xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
        \addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
            opacity=0, 
            fill opacity=1,
            table/row sep=\\,
            patch,
            patch type=polygon,
            vertex count=3,
            patch table with point meta={%
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 pt5 cdata
              0 4   7   3. \\
              7 8   1   2. \\
              8 6   2   3. \\
              6 4   2   3.53553 \\
              8 7   6   2.12132 \\
              7 4   6   2.12132 \\
              4 0   2   1. \\
              0 7   1   2. \\
              0 1   2   1. \\
              1 8   2   3. \\
              }
        ]
        table {
            x y z \\
            0   0   0 \\
            0   0   0.436694 \\
            0   0.436694    0.436694 \\
            0   0.5822  0.2911 \\
            0   0.873387    0 \\
            0.291187    0.5822  0.2911 \\
            0.436694    0.436694    0.436694 \\
            0.873387    0   0 \\
            0.873387    0   0.436694 \\
        };

        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

However, The result shades the same plane with different colors:

[image]

How can I make the triangles in the same plane to be equally colored?
Points that uses Mathematica to plot the convex hull can be seen from `InputForm[R]`. I have tried the same process with these points, and the result has a similar effect in the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is to some extent on the Mathematica side. You are getting one excess triangle: `7 8   1   2.`. If I remove it, I get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=126,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
            % colormap/greenyellow,
            colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!80!black!90) color(2)=(blue!80!black!70) color(3)=(blue!80!black!50) color(4)=(blue!80!black!30)},
            xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
        \addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
            opacity=0, 
            fill opacity=1,
            table/row sep=\\,
            patch,
            patch type=polygon,
            vertex count=3,
            patch table with point meta={%
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 pt5 cdata
              0 4   7   3. \\
              8 6   2   3. \\
              6 4   2   3.53553 \\
              8 7   6   2.12132 \\
              7 4   6   2.12132 \\
              4 0   2   1. \\
              0 7   1   2. \\
              0 1   2   1. \\
              1 8   2   3. \\
              }
        ]
        table {
            x y z \\
            0   0   0 \\
            0   0   0.436694 \\
            0   0.436694    0.436694 \\
            0   0.5822  0.2911 \\
            0   0.873387    0 \\
            0.291187    0.5822  0.2911 \\
            0.436694    0.436694    0.436694 \\
            0.873387    0   0 \\
            0.873387    0   0.436694 \\
        };
% removed       
%              7 8   1   2. \\

% \addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
%     opacity=1,
%     table/row sep=\\,nodes near coords/.append style={color=red},
%     only marks,nodes near coords=\coordindex
% ]
% table {
%     x y z\\
%             0   0   0 \\
%             0   0   0.436694 \\
%             0   0.436694    0.436694 \\
%             0   0.5822  0.2911 \\
%             0   0.873387    0 \\
%             0.291187    0.5822  0.2911 \\
%             0.436694    0.436694    0.436694 \\
%             0.873387    0   0 \\
%             0.873387    0   0.436694 \\
%         };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could debug yourself by restoring the triangle, resurrecting the commented out `\addplot` and setting `fill opacity=0.6,`. This hints at the culprit.

[image]

In principle, pgfplots should hide it, but I guess that since all its corners are on some visible edges, pgfplots decided to keep it.

Comment: But, if the triangles are in the same plane why their colors are different?

Comment: @user1993416 No, as you can see from the lower plot, the triangle `7--8--1` is *not* on the same plane. Rather, it is on the back, and should in principle be hidden by the other triangles.

Comment: even if I use `opacity=1` it will appear.

Comment: @user1993416 Yes. That's what I wrote in my answer. My feeling is that pgfplots get confused with that triangle, as I also wrote.